# PHP substring find infinite loop error

Tags: php, string, loops, infinite-loop

I have this code that for some reason it keeps in an infinite loop, when it is suppose to just print all possible substrings. This is part of the complete function. The purpose of the function is to return the indexes of the substring from string $str2 found in string $str1. Thanks a lot for the help.

```
$str1='QYDIKYTWNVPKIAPKS';
$str2='KYTWNVPKSS';
print($str1);echo"</br>";print($str2);echo"</br>";
function overlapping($str1,$str2) {
    $peptide1 = str_split($str1);
    $peptide2 = str_split($str2);
    $longest_seq=array();
    $len=count($peptide2)-1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($peptide1); ++$i) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($peptide2); ++$j) {
            if ($peptide2[$j]==$peptide1[$i]){
                $k=$j;
                $start=$j;
                $l=$i;
                $tmp=array();
                while ($peptide2[$k]==$peptide1[$l]){
                    array_push($tmp, $peptide2[$k]);
                    $substring=implode($tmp);
                        print $substring;
                        echo"</br>";
                    $k=$k+1;
                    $l=$l+1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe you have another idea of how to extract the index of a matching substring, I can also try that

Comment: @Dan, sorry, no, He is pushing onto $tmp in that statement. $peptide2 remains unchanged.

Comment: array_push($tmp, $peptide2[$k]); increases the length of the $tmp array, not the $peptide2 array. The problem comes when I use the same characters at the end of $str2. If I test it with $str2 as a perfect substring of $str1 it work perfect. But when I modify the $str2 at the start or end it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never check to insure that $k and $l are valid offsets. Check for it here :

```
while (isset($peptide2[$k]) && isset($peptide1[$l]) && $peptide2[$k]==$peptide1[$l]){
```

instead of

```
while ($peptide2[$k]==$peptide1[$l]){
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with your issue, but I always post-increment in my for loops.

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($peptide1); $i++) {
        // do stuff
    }
```